# How to remove old revisions of the documents in a couchdb database?

Tags: nosql, storage, couchdb, data-compaction

I have a very large database with some GB of data. And when I try to compact it's taking me more than 12 hours. Is there any other way to delete old revisions? Does the _revs_limit help in this. I can see that the revs limit of all databases is set to 1000. Does that mean even after compaction, 1000 revisions will remain on the couchdb?

Comment: Yes compaction is guided by the revs_limit.  I recommend looking at your requirements and use cases, likely you may drastically reduce revs_limit for relief.  Do you have many deleted documents?

Comment: The documents in that database are getting updated every day. So I guess there will be a lot of revisions. Does change the rev limit cause any problem. I read at many places it will affect the replication and concurrency.

Comment: indeed altering `rev_limits` has consequences but it's configurable for just such a reason - it's all a matter of use cases and fine tuning, all of which cannot be answered here.

Answer (score -1):

ou cannot delete an old revision of a single document. This is because the old revisions are only used by CouchDB internally for concurrency control and you shouldn't have to worry about these revisions. If you want to remove all old revisions in order to shrink the size of your database, you can run compaction.